# integrated whatsapp-web.js with vuejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, vue.js, whatsapi

I'm new to vuejs ..

I don't understand how to link this vue js and whatapp-web.js

https://github.com/pedroslopez/whatsapp-web.js

install

```
vue init webpack-simple whatsapp-vue
cd whatsapp-vue
npm i whatsapp-web.js
npm install
npm run dev
```

main.js

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import App from './App.vue'
const { Client } = require('whatsapp-web.js');
const client = new Client();

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  render: h => h(App)
})
```

i got error when npm run dev

```
client?cd17:167 ./node_modules/whatsapp-web.js/index.js
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (24:4)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
|     List: require('./src/structures/List'),
|     Buttons: require('./src/structures/Buttons'),
|     ...Constants
| };
| 
 @ ./src/main.js 4:15-41
 @ multi (webpack)-dev-server/client?http://localhost:8080 webpack/hot/dev-server ./src/main.js
```

but it works with momentjs

[image]

can someone help me with example ?

thank you

Comment: whatapp-web.js uses pupper for headless chromium which runs on the server while vuejs is client app hence it cant run that. For your concept to work create nodejs api which houses the whatsapp-web.js then the vuejs will consume the api